# Get Controls/Views from dynamic content Tab

Tags: android, tabcontrol

I have created tabs and their content from a database.  Now I need help figuring out how to get the user entered values from those controls - how to get a list of the controls on the tabs (so the data can be saved).  Here is a condensed sample of how I'm populating the tabs contents:

```
public View createTabContent(String tag)
{
SQLiteDatabase db2 = openOrCreateDatabase(msDbFile, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor cList = db2.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CheckList WHERE CatID=" + tag, null);
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(FormChecklist.this);
tl.setBackgroundColor(new Color().WHITE);
while(cList.moveToNext())
{   
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(FormChecklist.this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     /* Create the row-content. */
    TextView lblQuestion = new TextView(FormChecklist.this);
    lblQuestion.setText(cList.getString(2));
    lblQuestion.setTag(tag);
    /* Add control to row. */
    tr.addView(lblQuestion);

    CheckBox chkCompleted = new CheckBox(FormChecklist.this);
    chkCompleted.setText("Completed");
    chkCompleted.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    chkCompleted.setTag(tag);
    /* Add control to row. */
    tr.addView(chkCompleted);

    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
db2.close();
return tl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No replies, but finally figured out, hopefully someone will find this info helpful.
Approach I took was modifying my createTabContent adding an ID for the TableLayout:

```
tl.setId(1000 + miTlCnt);
```

Then in my save routine I loop through controls like so:

```
for (int i = 1000 + miTlCnt; i > 1000; i--)
{ 
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(i);
    if (tl != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tl.getChildCount(); j++)
        {
            TableRow row = (TableRow)tl.getChildAt(j);
            CheckBox chkCompleted = (CheckBox)row.getChildAt(1);
        }
    }
}
```